# Reverse tethering Macbook Pro and iPad over BT extremely slow

Tags: bluetooth, macbook, ipad, tethering, reverse-tethering

Sharing my Mac's internet over Bluetooth is extremely slow, with about 0.50 mbps download and often 0.00 mbps upload. My mac is connected wirelessly to a router and gets about 115 mbps download and 10 mbps upload. Why is the connection on the iPad so slow? I would use wifi tethering except that I can't connect my mac to the router using an Ethernet cable. Even so, shouldn't BT 4.0 be able to handle much faster speeds?

Comment: Bluetooth is pretty slow to begin with, before overheads you'll be lucky to get 2mbps, after overheads and interference 1mbps is optimistic. There's a reason it is only used for audio, mice and keyboards.

Comment: Doesn't BT 4.0 support up to 250 Mbps though?

Comment: Bluetooth HS might, but that requires specific support on both sides and is essentially a Bluetooth negotiated WiFi PHY connection. Bluetooth itself is low data rate.

Comment: Is there a way to check if HS is supported in macOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bluetooth is a low data rate protocol and is generally capable of less than 2Mbps under normal circumstances.

Bluetooth 3 [supported a "High Speed" mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth#Bluetooth_3.0_+_HS) which used a WiFi link to achieve 24mbit, but is not "real" Bluetooth:

> Bluetooth v3.0 + HS provides theoretical data transfer speeds of up to 24 Mbit/s, though not over the Bluetooth link itself. Instead, the Bluetooth link is used for negotiation and establishment, and the high data rate traffic is carried over a colocated 802.11 link.

This requires hardware and software support and generally was not well received or used.

For *core* Bluetooth support you have the option of 1, 2 or 3 Mbits, [depending on implementation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth#Implementation) and support by *both* sides of the connection.

> Originally, Gaussian frequency-shift keying (GFSK) modulation was the only modulation scheme available. Since the introduction of Bluetooth 2.0+EDR, π/4-DQPSK (differential quadrature phase-shift keying) and 8-DPSK modulation may also be used between compatible devices. Devices functioning with GFSK are said to be operating in basic rate (BR) mode, where an **instantaneous bit rate of 1 Mbit/s is possible**. The term Enhanced Data Rate (EDR) is used to describe π/4-DPSK and 8-DPSK schemes, **each giving 2 and 3 Mbit/s respectively.** The combination of these (BR and EDR) modes in Bluetooth radio technology is classified as a BR/EDR radio.
>
> In 2019, **Apple published an extension called HDR which supports data rates up to 8Mbit/s**.

The 8Mbit extension is unlikely to be common, and would require hardware support. I doubt a simple software upgrade would enable it except on devices that already support it.

It may be that you are thinking of WiFiDirect which is a high speed WiFi connection with a Bluetooth style ad-hoc connection.